# how to differentiate .mp4 Audio file and .mp4 Video File In ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

when I am uploading audio and video file of .mp4 extension using file upload Control its uploading successfully but its difficult to differentiate that it is audio or Video while Creating Thumbnail that file.

Comment: put an image convertor to identify when vedio or mp3 file uploading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try identifying MIME of file. In other words content-type:

```
string contentType = flFile.PostedFile.ContentType;
if("video/mp4" == contentType.ToLower()){
    //its video
}else if("audio/mp4" == contentType.ToLower()){
     //its audio
}
```